# which hash function is secure in password authentication?

Tags: c, hash, tcp, cryptography, salt

I want to do a application of client - server in which authentication should be there . I heard lot of cryptographic algorithm . But I want some suggestion about good cryptographic algorithm . I want to implement using C language . Can I use Hash function with some salt ? but my concern is how can I implement in C language . Any sample code is there to implement for hashing with salted password for authentication ? at the time of signup when he is new user , how can I send password to server with encryption ? suggest some codes in C program or some materials in C program . Thanks .

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/crypt.html) which discusses the C `crypt` function.  It takes a password and a salt and returns an encrypted string which you can save to your database.

Comment: The algorithms BCrypt, SCrypt and PBKDF2 are currently recommended for hashing passwords, all have a cost factor to control the time to calculate a hash.

Answer (score 1):

The blogoverflow page has a good [article](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/) about storing passwords, including suggestions of hashes. Note that for hashing passwords, you want a very *slow* hash, because you only have to compute it once on correct login, but an attacker will have to compute it a lot of times in order to brute-force the password should your database somehow be compromised.